# Isn't OnGUI and Event cyclical?

Tags: unity

Here's what I don't understand about Events:

the documentation says that `Events correspond to user input (key presses, mouse actions), or are UnityGUI layout or rendering events. For each event OnGUI is called in the scripts; so OnGUI is potentially called multiple times per frame. Event.current corresponds to "current" event inside OnGUI call.`

the documentation pertaining to onGUI states that it has`one call per event`

That doesn't make sense to me, because I know I can call Events within OnGUI.

I have an OnGUI function that draws a grid using x and y nested for loops, then checks using `Event.current.mousePosition` if your mouse is hovering over a grid block. What I don't get is how OnGUI is ever called, if OnGUI is only called when an event occurs, but I have the event inside OnGUI so how can you ever check if the event is being called inside a script that is only called after the event is called?

I know that probably sounds confusing -- I'm just puzzled by the seemingly cyclical nature of ongui.

Comment: `Event.current.mousePosition` is not triggering an event, it's accessing the event that triggered the current `OnGUI` method call. `OnGUI` is called once per frame and once for every event.

Comment: so what would be the difference between something like Event.current.mousePosition and just Input.mouseposition?

Comment: Between those two? Likely nothing. However, `Input` and `Event.current` do not overlap each other entirely. Comparing them isn't really practical.

Answer (score 3):

> because I know I can call Events within OnGUI.

Accessing data from the current event i.e. `Event.current.mousePosition` is not "calling an event", at least not in the sense that you're activating the event so triggers an `OnGUI` call. As the documentation says, that you posted in your question:

> `Event.current` corresponds to "current" event inside OnGUI call.

That means using `Event.current.mousePosition` is just accessing the event that triggered the `OnGUI` call, not triggering a new event.

Events are triggered outside of `OnGUI` via user interaction with the UI.

There is one [event type](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.html) that happens every frame, no matter the user input, [`Repaint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.Repaint.html). `Repaint` is sent every frame when the GUI is redrawn. This is the last event processed. This is where your grid is drawn every frame, because this event happens every frame.